# How does the browser behave/handle the same file name requests on the first page load?

Tags: html, performance, dom, browser

Example:

```
<section>
   <link href="slider.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"/>
   <script src="slider.js" defer />

   <h2> Tshirts </h2>
   ...
</section>

<section>
   <link href="slider.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"/>
   <script src="slider.js" defer />

   <h2> Hats </h2>
   ...
</section>
```

How will the browser handle the requests of same files on the same page? Will it fetch the first one then ignore all other files of the same name or...?? On the first fetch of the first filename I assume this will be cached? What is the correct term to search for this topic to help further my research?

Comment: The [Fetch](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/) specification contains a detailed algorithm of how resources are retrieved. You'll need to analyse it very carefully to establish what should happen. (Note however, that without a `rel="stylesheet"` attribute, your link elements won't retrieve anything.)

Comment: Did you look at the network panel?